# left join subquery access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

the following code works fine (i.e. doesn't error) However it joins everything from subquery "e". I would like it return [Total Cancellations] only and NOT [Business Unit]

Appreciate the help

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT c.*,b.[Total Bookings]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.[business unit], count(a.[lookup_id]) as [Total Colleagues in DMS]
FROM EVERYTHING AS a
GROUP BY a.[business unit]

)  AS c 


LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.[business unit], count(a.[lookup_id]) as [Total Bookings]
FROM EVERYTHING AS a
WHERE a.[session_code]is not null
GROUP BY a.[business unit]

)  AS b ON c.[business unit]=b.[business unit]

)  AS d LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.[business unit], count(a.[lookup_id]) as [Total Cancellations]
FROM EVERYTHING AS a
WHERE a.[Has Booking been cancelled (Yes / No)]=1
group by a.[business unit]

)  AS e ON d.[business unit]=e.[business unit];

    enter code here
```

Comment: You are using `SELECT *`, which I expect will return _all_ columns from the join query.  Restrict this by explicitly mentioning columns which you want to retain.

Comment: how do I post code in a response? thanks

Comment: Please do NOT post your query as a comment!

Comment: What is *access*? Did you mean MS Access? Tags explicitly advise not to use *access* for the MS Office program but *ms-access*. Adjust title as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
   SELECT d.[business unit]
    ,d.[Total Colleagues in DMS]
    ,d.[Total Bookings]
    ,e.[Total Cancellations]
--,f.columnname
FROM (
    SELECT c.*
        ,b.[Total Bookings]
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [business unit]
            ,count([lookup_id]) AS [Total Colleagues in DMS]
        FROM EVERYTHING
        GROUP BY [business unit]
        ) c
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [business unit]
            ,count([lookup_id]) AS [Total Bookings]
        FROM EVERYTHING
        WHERE [session_code] IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY [business unit]
        ) b ON c.[business unit] = b.[business unit]
    ) d
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [business unit]
        ,count([lookup_id]) AS [Total Cancellations]
    FROM EVERYTHING
    WHERE [Has Booking been cancelled (Yes / No)] = 1
    GROUP BY [business unit]
    ) e ON d.[business unit] = e.[business unit];
    --LEFT JOIN (....) f ON ...
```

Comment: Amazing. Works great. Thank you

Comment: You can either upvote or select the answer when it works for you.

Comment: If I needed to added a further left join, how would I do that? thanks again

Comment: Again thanks for your help.. I've changed the query and added the extra LEFT JOIN but it errors. Much appreciated. Not sure where I'm going wrong here.